# Passive Imperatives

Tags: movement, passive, malay, imperative

The optional subject of an imperative is usually the second person pronoun. I've found something quite peculiar in Malay, where the utterance is an imperative and is passive but the subject is not the second person.

```
Benda yang pelik jangan di-tegur     (*[oleh kamu])

Thing COMP weird NEG    PASS-mention (*[by 2.SG]) 

Don't mention things that are weird
```

The context of this utterance is one where 2 persons notice something weird, thinking that it's a ghostly entity or something paranormal and one person mentions what s/he sees, smells or hears. It's something like the 'knock on wood' gesture. The active counterpart of this utterance is the following:

```
(Kamu) jangan tegur   benda yang pelik   

(2.SG) NEG    mention thing COMP weird   

(You) don't mention things that are weird
```

One can also focus-move the arguments:

> Benda yang pelik jangan ditegur.
>
> Jangan ditegur, benda yang pelik.
>
> Benda yang pelik, jangan tegur.
>
> Jangan tegur benda yang pelik.

In transformational grammar, it is said that the internal argument is raised and the thematic subject is turned into an optional adjunct by-phrase. Using the by-phrase in the utterance above is anomalous. However, an imperative necessarily needs a second person subject in English and Malay, but the utterance above demonstrates that there is a mix up somehow.

The negator "jangan" is a direct order which means "do not". This means that the subject absolutely has to be the second person. In English, it would be very strange to use "do not" with a 3rd person subject.

How is this utterance possibly an imperative when the grammatical subject is not the second person?

How can one register this utterance as an imperative when SpecIP has been occupied by the moved internal argument, not the second person?

Comment: **Example** **1**  "Nothing is to be said about this outside these four walls." 3rd person passive optative.

Comment: **Example** **2** "None of you are to be seen by the judges before the competition." 3rd/ ?2nd person passive optative/  ?imperative.

Comment: @Hugh - Good examples, but what makes your examples different from the utterance at hand is that the negator "jangan" is a direct order, which means "do not", and necessarily requires the second person. Maybe I should add that to the question, for clarity's sake.

Comment: But from your analysis, it is clearly not true that _jangan_ necessarily requires the second person.

Comment: That's what makes it peculiar. "Jangan" semantically selects (I don't know whether this is the right term to use) a 2nd person subject, but on the surface, the subject is the moved internal argument. It's barely an analysis - more like an observation.

Comment: Interesting data! Why are you sure that _benda_ is the subject? Can't it be a fronted object, with the 2nd person subject obligatorily _pro_?

Comment: @IvanKapitonov One point is that a topicalised constituent usually has pause-intonation. There is no pause after ''benda yang pelik''. There is a pause if "jangan ditegur" is fronted though. Neither could this be a case of focalisation as there is no contrastive reading available.